# How can I access a 2D array from another file on PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array called $lang2 on one file I called 'table.php'. After the form on table.php is submitted, it goes to another file I called 'process.php'. I want to be able to iterate through $lang2 on the process.php file.

On 'table.php', I created the 2D array like this:

```
$lang2 = array_fill(0, count($items2), array_fill(0, 4, "e"));
$counter = 0;
foreach ($items2 as $item2) {
    $lang2[$counter][0] = $item2['localstring'];
    $lang2[$counter][1] = $item2['itemtype'];
    $lang2[$counter][2] = $item2['object_id'];
    $lang2[$counter][3] = $item2['local_id'];
    $counter++;
}
```

When I print the $lang2 array using print_r on 'table.php', the array is outputted. However, when I try to print array on 'process.php', my output is
`Array ()`

I have included my 'table.php' file on 'process.php' and have tested that other variables are able to be used from one file to another. I just can't seem to get it to work for 2D arrays. The data from the $lang2 array comes from a database. I have tried making a 2D that doesn't have data coming from a database and there wasn't a difference, so I don't think that's the problem.

I have tried tweaking the code so that when the form is submitted, it stays on the same page, but that didn't seem to work out. I've also tried making a copy of $lang2 just in case the database had something to do with it, but that didn't make much of a difference.

What I'm expected is the array to print out like it does when I print it on the 'table.php' file. Something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => string1 
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 1 
        [3] => 13 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => string2 
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 3 
        [3] => 15 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => string3 
        [1] => 5 
        [2] => 1 
        [3] => 103 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => string4 
        [1] => 5 
        [2] => 4 
        [3] => 104 
    ) 
)
```

Here is a link to github with all of the code: https://github.com/SarahP15/amdb_table.git

$lang2 is created on line 164 in 'table.php'.

I'm sorry for all the commented out bits, I'm trying to isolate the code to find what's wrong haha

If you guys had any advice, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `I just can't seem to get it to work for 2D arrays`...they're not instrinsically different to any other variables, in this respect. If you wrote `include table.php` inside `process.php` before you try to access `$lang2` then it should be populated - assuming the code in table.php goes definitely through the part needed in order to generate the data. It would help a lot if we have a [mre] of the issue, end-to-end. We can't tell much from just a snippet of the isolated, working bit, and only a verbal description of the rest. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Thinking around the issue, `$lang2` appears to being built from the other array `$items2`. SO how is the `$items2` array created?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! $lang2 is populated from a database and I used a foreach statement with $items2 to put the values (from the DB) into the array. I'm trying to isolate my code to find the problem so I'm sorry for all the commented out bits, but here is a link to github with all of the code: https://github.com/SarahP15/amdb_table.git

Comment: `$lang2 is populated from a database`...really? not according to your code. It seems to be populated based on the content of `$items2`. Maybe _that_ is populated from a database? Either way, please [edit] your question with a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Just linking us to a github dump of your code isn't acceptable because a) we may have to wade through a ton of irrelevant stuff to get to the useful bit, and b) that link could die or change after a while, making the question useless to future readers (who are just as much the audience as you or I are) - see also [ask] and the [tour] and the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Where's that `process.php` that reads the data? How do you transmit it from the first to the second script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On table.php, you can include the $lang2 array as a hidden input in the form using json_encode like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lang2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($lang2)); ?>">
```

On process.php, you can retrieve the $lang2 array from the POST data using json_decode like this:

```
$lang2 = json_decode($_POST['lang2'], true); // retrieve the $lang2 array from the hidden input
```

And add a submit action to your form like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I'm only about 2 weeks into using PHP but spent 4 days trying to figure this part out, so this is definitely going on my toolbelt :)